# Google Apps Script - Going up from bottom of sheet to an available value

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to do a macro in google sheets where I select a point in column N (in this case N100) and then simulate control up button to move up to the next available value in column N. But when I do this, I see the cell that's activated is the top of the column (looks like control up is pressed twice).

The code I have is below, any ideas on why this seems to be the case?

```
function ClearFormq() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Team1");
    sheet.getRange("N100").activate()
 sheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).activate();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `getNextDataCell` method works on boundaries. It will find the next boundary between the cell you are in, and a cell that has the inverse of `Range#isBlank` of the current cell. The selected cell will be the one in the appropriate row or column in the side of the boundary that has data. In other words, if N100 has a formula or a value, even if the formula calculation yields `""`, then the next cell is the one that borders a cell that has no formula and no value.

Comment: Please also confirm that this is a macro, e.g. a function you manually execute, and not a time based trigger. Consider a more robust and useful method other than `activate` to debug your script, such as modifying values or formatting.